# Proper way of dealing with templates and views in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Osoascam/D87cg/6/) with the following view:

```html
<ul id="modules">
    <li id="modulePersonal" data-bind="template: 'personalDataTemplate'"></li>
    <li id="moduleAccounts" data-bind="template: 'accountsDataTemplate'"></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="personalDataTemplate">
    <h3 class="klavikaBold">Your Details</h3>
    <div class="content">
        {{if loggedIn}}
        <p>This is what you've been telling us:</p>
        <dl class="pairDefinition">
            <dt>Name</dt>
            <dd>${name}</dd>
            <dt>Gender</dt>
            <dd>${gender}</dd>
            <dt>Age</dt>
            <dd>${age}</dd>
            <dt>Country</dt>
            <dd>${country}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <p>Hey, you Alpha male! Come here
        and give us all of your personal
        data! We promise we won't give it
        for free to anybody!</p>
    {{/if}}    
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="accountsDataTemplate">  
    <h3>Your accounts</h3>
    <div class="content">
        <p> There are 2 messages from Yahoo, 1 from Lumosity and 5 from Tweetland</p>
        <ul class="listSeparated line">
            <li>
                <dl class="pairDefinition">
                    <dt>Yahoo</dt>
                    <dd><a href="#">Account Details</a></dd>
                    <dt>Email</dt>
                    <dd>blabisbla@yahoo.com</dd>
                </dl>
            </li>
            <li>
                <dl class="pairDefinition">
                    <dt>Lumosity</dt>
                    <dd><a href="#">Account Details</a></dd>
                    <dt>Username</dt>
                    <dd>ilovetheiradds</dd>
                </dl>
            </li>
            <li>
                <dl class="pairDefinition">
                    <dt>Tweet Land</dt>
                    <dd><a href="#">Account Details</a></dd>
                    <dt>Username</dt>
                    <dd>costaricangamer</dd>
                    <dt>Games</dt>
                    <dd>Lovecity, CarRace, Unit</dd>
                </dl>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

And this code:

```
(function($) {

    var userDetails = {
        "name": "Óscar Acuña",
        "country": "Costa Rica",
        "province": "San José",
        "district": "San Andrés",
        "zip": "123456",
        "birthday": "12/12/1990",
        "gender": "Male",
        "hotnessIndex": "6.8",
        "smell": "Nice if not sweaty"
    };


    // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
    var viewModel = {
        loggedIn : "yeah",
        name: userDetails.name,
        country: userDetails.country,
        province: userDetails.province,
        gender: userDetails.gender,
        age: getAgeSortOf(userDetails.birthday) + " years old"
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    function getAgeSortOf(birthday) {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(birthday).getFullYear();

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Please note I elaborated the template just for the first li.

Let's imagine there might be up to 10 `li`s, each containing different data (so the idea of them sharing a single view is unlikely). The data comes from a vendor, so they can change the names and order when they see fit.

You see one template stores the different states it might have. My question is, do you think that's a secure approach? After all, the real data is being feed by an Ajax request (here represented by a hard-coded JSON userDetails).

In addition, which is the most flexible way of setting variables that determine flow? (for example loggedIn : "yeah", if you remove it, the other view is displayed). Here I'm coding them right in the viewModel, but they can actually be coded outside... Is this the right approach or I'm missusing knockout? I've never dealt with a MVVM framework in front end so I might be a little confused.

Comment: Oscar - can you boil your question down to it's essence?

Comment: What is it that you want to know?

Comment: Yes, of course. Basically the question is... If I have two or more states which are determined by a global variable (the user's computer brand, whether he's logged in or not, etc), where should I set that variable so that knockout renders the proper data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to be using a `ko.observableArray()` for holding your user details. If I'm understanding correctly you want multiple `li` elements - one for each `UserDetails` that is returned from your ajax call. Your view model would look like this:

```
viewModel = {
  loggedIn: ko.observable(true),
  users: ko.observableArray([])
}
```

You then add each object to the array by calling `viewModel.users.push(newUser)`

the template to enumerate the users:

```
<ul data-bind="template:{name:'userTmpl', foreach:users}"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the explanation I was looking for!